# opensearch/elasticsearch query second index based on results from first

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

is there a way to get results from a second index based on the results from the first?

For example, patients index and appointments index:

- patients index => id, name, phone, organization
- appointments index => id, patientId

  POST patients/_search
  {
  "query": {
  "bool": {
  "must": [
  {
  "match": {
  "organization.S": "whatever"
  }
  }
  ]
  }
  }
  }

  POST appointments/_count
  {
  "query": {
  "bool": {
  "must": [
  {
  "match": {
  "patient.S": "patientId"
  }
  }
  ]
  }
  }
  }

the first one would get me my patients, and the second one would count how many appointments a patient has.

How can I merge them to get from the first one the patients + their number of appointments in the same query?

Basically, a graphql kind of thing where the number of appointments would be resolved into the first query in parallel or something of the sort.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [term aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html).

```
POST patients/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "organization.S": "whatever"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "patient.S",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: the field type should be `keyword` for the aggs. If you get any error, try with `your_field_name.keyword`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! But how would that get the appointments number for that patient? In that example we're only in the "patients" index and are not querying anything from the "appointments" index

Comment: @user3812411 I just realized that you have multiple indices :/ Maybe terms lookup query can solve your problem
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup-example

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to see all patients and with all organizations, you can use the following aggregation.

```
POST patients/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "organizations": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "organization.S",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "patients": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "patient.S",
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```